# Pipe the output of a command if it is successful

Tags: shell, pipe, output

```
INPUT_FILE=`ls -rt $MY_DIR/FILE.*.xml | head -1 | xargs basename`
```

I wanted to execute the second command (`head -1`) only if the first command is successful. How do I improve this command?

Comment: What do you mean by successful? `ls` will not fail.

Comment: But the glob can fail if there are no matching files.

Comment: @Matteo I just typed `ls senthunth` it failed (returned an error code).

Comment: What is the danger of running `head`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
INPUT_FILE=`ls -rt "$MY_DIR"/FILE.*.xml | head -1 | xargs -r basename`
```

Passing `xargs` the `-r` flag will cause it to only run `basename` if reads at
least one item from standard input (`head -1`).

`head -1` will run but you won't see or capture any output from it.

Also, if you don't want the user to see any error output from `ls`, you can redirect `ls`'s stderr stream to `/dev/null`.

```
INPUT_FILE=`ls -rt "$MY_DIR"/FILE.*.xml 2> /dev/null | head -1 | xargs -r basename`
```

Also note that I added quotation marks around `$MY_DIR`. That way, the command will not fail if `$MY_DIR` contains spaces.

If you're using a modern shell such as bash, you should use a `$( )` capture shell instead of backticks. You should also consider changing the style of your variables. You should generally avoid using all-uppercase variable names in scripts. That style is generally reserved for reserved and environmental variables.

```
input_file=$(ls -rt "$my_dir"/FILE.*.xml 2> /dev/null | head -1 | xargs -r basename)
```

Comment: Doesn't this b0rk if there are no files?

Comment: Actually: `ls -rt GLOB 2>/dev/null | head -n1 | xargs -r basename` works.

Comment: @MelBoyce: I've added that to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: ls is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @cinelli: That is true. I was just answering the question.

Answer (score 9):

In a pipe line, all commands are started and run concurrently, not one after the other. So you need to store the output somewhere.

```
if ls_output=$(ls -rtd -- "$MY_DIR"/FILE.*.xml); then
  first_file=$(printf '%s\n' "$ls_output" | head -n 1)
  first_file_name=$(basename -- "$first_file")
fi
```

Note that it assumes file names don't contain newline characters. Using `xargs` would also mean problems with blank characters, single and double quotes and backslashes. Leaving variables unquoted would mean problems with space, tab and wildcard characters. Forgetting `--` would mean problems with filenames starting with `-`.

To get the basename of the oldest file with `zsh` without any of those restrictions on characters (also avoids the problem of the limited size of arguments to a command):

```
 first_file_name=($MY_DIR/FILE.*.xml(Om[1]:t))
```

If there's no match, that command will fail and abort the script. You can also do:

```
 first_file_name=($MY_DIR/FILE.*.xml(NOm[1]:t))
```

In which case the `first_file_name` array will contain 1 element if there's a match or 0 if not. You can then do:

```
 if (($#first_file_name)); then
    printf 'Match: %s\n' $first_file_name
 else
    echo >&2 No match
 fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Find the latest modified file in a directory:

```
latest() {
  local file path=${1:-.} ext=${2-} latest
  for file in "${path%/}"/*"$ext"; do 
    [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && latest=$file
  done
  [[ $latest ]] && printf '%s\n' "$latest"
}
```

Usage: `latest [directory/path/ [.extension]]`

Instead of calling out to `basename`, use parameter expansion.

```
in_file=$(latest in/my/dir .xml)
base_fn=${in_file##*/} base_fn=${base_fn%.*}
```

In a directory with these contents:

```
foo.xml bar.xml baz.xml newest.xml
```

The contents of the base_fn variable would be: `newest`

To use this properly to serve the purpose of your request:

```
check_dir=/path/to/check
check_ext=.xml
if in_file=$(latest "$check_dir" "$check_ext"); then
  base_fn=${in_file##*/} base_fn=${base_fn%.*}
else
  printf '%s\n' "No file found in $check_dir" >&2
fi
```

EDIT: upon review of the question, i have realized that the `ls` command in question is looking for the *oldest* file in a directory. this same function could be renamed to `oldest` and have `[[ $file -ot $oldest ]] && oldest=$file` instead to achieve the same effect. apologies for any confusion.

the important thing to note is that you absolutely, under no circumstances ever in mankind, should not parse the output of ls. never.

Comment: Note that contrary to the `ls`-based approaches, if there are symlinks, the modification time of the target of the symlinks will be considered (add the `-L` option to `ls` to get the same behaviour there).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifne` from `moreutils`. It checks whether the input it gets is non-empty (as opposed to checking the return value of the piped in command).

```
INPUT_FILE=`ls -rt $MY_DIR/FILE.*.xml | ifne head -1 | xargs basename`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option here is:

```
ls -rf $MY_DIR/FILE.*.xml
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      INPUT_FILE=`ls -rt $MY_DIR/FILE.*.xml|head -1|xargs basename `
else
      echo "Error!"
fi
```

if there is no file then the return code of ls is 2 but if it finds some file will be 0.

Comment: Instead of comparing `$?` against `0`, you can do this: `if ls -rf $MY_DIR/FILE.*.xml ; then`.

Comment: Also, you can redirect the output of the first comand to `/dev/null`. `ls -rf $MY_DIR/FILE.*.xml &> /dev/null`. That way, the user won't see the extra output.